# Duplicate customer in Stripe laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-7, laravel-6.2

I started today Stripe in Laravel 6. I used below code and ran it two times.

```
$stripeCustomer = $this->User->createOrGetStripeCustomer();
```

**[As per the instructions here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/billing#creating-customers)** same user can't be created two times but after running the code 2 times, it created the duplicate customer.

Please check the screenshot below.

Can I delete the customer from stripe? I saw the Laravel library. But seems like there is no delete stripe customer function in cashier

[image]

Am I missing anything? Why did it create the duplicate customer?

Comment: This can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222249/stripe-api-checking-for-existing-card

Comment: use `email` as a `unique`

Comment: Email is already a unique column. When I added first time, It created the customer as well as the customer in stripe but after that I rollback the transaction. In this way the customer created in database gets deleted automatically and lives only in stripe. When I repeat the same process, it create the duplicate customer in stripe. Are you following my point?

Comment: Email isn't a unique constraint in Stripe, so this is something specific to Cashier - and I'm unfortunately not sure what the problem is as I'm not familiar enough with Cashier.